# Generate Vote Counting Sheet From Values In Another Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a worksheet that allows the end user to select from a set of districts and have subdistricts populate along with their vote strength. For instance

District = 5

Candidates = 3

Subdistricts

```
Subdistrict     Vote Strength
   U                  456
   E                  442
   R                  876
   T                  312
   B                  256
   S                  643
```

I'd like to create a button that let's an end user create an additional sheet that will populate based off of the values in their district selection. The newly created sheet would create a "ballot" of sorts. On the first sheet, they'd indicated the number of candidates and the new sheet would populate similar to this

```
           U    E   R   T   B   S
```

Candidate 1
Candidate 2
Candidate 3

The end user would input *raw* vote (a number between 0 and 4), which would be multiplied by the vote strength in sheet 1, producing a weighted vote calculator that scales up or down depending on the number of subdistricts a certain district has.

The logic would essentially be:

- Create a new sheet
- Horizontally add column headers for each subdistrict in sheet 1 and add rows for total number of candidates in sheet 1
- As raw votes are entered, a mirrored table from the table created in sheet 2 is produced with raw vote calculated

Comment: I'm 100% positive the solution is VBA--and since I've not got a ton of experience in VBA, links and info to potential solutions would be useful as well. I don't mind researching, just need to be pointed in the right direction of where to go.

Comment: What does District = 5 do? And are there always 6 subdistricts?

Comment: It's just a cell value populated from a data validation list that the end user selects. The number of subdistricts will be different for all of the districts.

Comment: Here are the steps you will need to research *just enter each step into Google) in order to get to your result: 1) Create Input Box with Drop down -This will be the input box 2) Sheets.Add Method - This will create a new worksheet 3) For Loop with Cell.value - this will help you with horizontal headers and vertical column names

Comment: If you get stuck, post your code and I will help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated the loop to show the formula instead:

```
For m = 2 To i + 2

    Cells(CandidateCount + 1, m).Formula = _
    "=SUM(" & ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(2, m), ActiveSheet.Cells(CandidateStart, m)).Address(False, False) & ")"

Next m
```

Comment: Technically, this works but only by summing up the current contents of the cells, not by inserting a formula that will dynamically sum up the cell contents in reaction to changes. Trying to avoid this by only requiring a single one-time click and script run for the new spreadsheet to be formed. Is there a way to inject the actual formula into the cell?

Comment: I have updated the code to show the formula instead.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to @[VBA Pete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6110371/vba-pete) for putting me on the right track, I managed to create the basic functionality. I'm now stuck on this step

> As raw votes are entered, a mirrored table from the table created in sheet 2 is produced with raw vote calculated

I need to accomplish <s>two things</s> one more step:

<s>1. Create a data validation requirement in a For Loop for a column range that disallows more raw votes being counted than people who are actually present. I have this stored in a variable in the code below as MembersPresent.</s>
 2. Populate the weighted vote *after* end user input is recorded. **This can be accomplished by inserting a dynamic formula into cells inside a For loop using variables. I've seperated the working code from the non-working code below**

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add Before:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    i = Sheet1.Cells(8, 6).Value
    CandidateCount = Sheet1.Cells(11, 8).Value
    CandidateState = CandidateCount + 1
    SheetName = Sheet1.Cells(13, 8).Value
    OrSheetName = Sheet1.Cells(13, 8).Value
    v = 0
    For Each Sheet In Worksheets
        If SheetName = Sheet.Name Then
            SheetName = OrSheetName & "_Ballot" & v
            v = v + 1
        End If
    Next Sheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = SheetName
    For x = 1 To i
    b = 15 + x
        Subdistrict = Cells(b, 2).Value
        MembersPresent = Cells(b, 6).Value
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, (x + 1)).Value = Subdistrict
        For a = 2 To 6
            ActiveSheet.Cells(a, x + 1).Value = 0
            With ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(a, x + 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(a, x + 1)).Validation
                .Add Type:=xlValidateWholeNumber, _
                AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="0", Formula2:=MembersPresent
                .InputTitle = "Integers"
                .ErrorTitle = "Integers"
                .InputMessage = "Enter an integer from 0 to " & MembersPresent
                .ErrorMessage = "You must enter a number no less than 0 and no greater than the number of members in attendance: " & MembersPresent
            End With
        Next a
    Next x
    For b = 1 To CandidateCount

        Named = "Candidate Name" & " " & b
        ActiveSheet.Cells((b + 1), 1).Value = Named
    Next b
    ActiveSheet.Cells(CandidateCount + 1, 1).Value = "Raw Vote Totals"
```

Broken Code that looks like what I think I want

```vb
    For m = 2 To i + 2
            SumRange = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(2, m), ActiveSheet.Cells(CandidateStart, m)).Select
            ActiveSheet.Cells(CandidateCount + 1, m).Formula = "=SUM(" & SumRange & ")"
        Next m
```

Comment: Can you give examples of your two issues?

Comment: See edits, I've updated the code and shown the broken code

Comment: Just posted an answer. Let me know if that fixes your code.